# How to convert a matrix to a dataframe in R by keeping the indices in the first and second column?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix like this:

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

and I want to convert it to a `data.frame` such that the first and the second column shows the indices in the matrix and the third column shows the number, like this:

```
> D
   i j  v
1  1 1  1
2  1 2  3
3  2 1  2
4  2 2  4
```

Is there any command or straight solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R option using `col` + `row`

```
data.frame(
  i = c(t(row(mat))),
  j = c(t(col(mat))),
  v = c(t(mat))
)
```

gives

```
  i j v
1 1 1 1
2 1 2 3
3 2 1 2
4 2 2 4
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` pipe friendly syntax

```r
mat <- matrix(1:4, 2)

library(dplyr)

expand.grid(seq_len(nrow(mat)), seq_len(ncol(mat))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(values = mat[Var1, Var2])

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    Var1  Var2 values
#>   <int> <int>  <int>
#> 1     1     1      1
#> 2     2     1      2
#> 3     1     2      3
#> 4     2     2      4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `expand.grid` to create row/column index.

```
mat <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
transform(expand.grid(i = seq(nrow(mat)), j = seq(ncol(mat))), v = c(mat))

#  i j v
#1 1 1 1
#2 2 1 2
#3 1 2 3
#4 2 2 4
```

Comment: What is the difference from doing `cbind(i = 1:nrow(mat), j = 1:ncol(mat), v = c(mat))`?

Comment: There is no difference in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this way.

```r
mat = cbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 4))

n_row = nrow(mat)
n_col = ncol(mat)
total_row = n_row * n_col

out = data.frame( i = rep( seq_len( n_row ), each = n_row ),
                  j = rep( seq_len( n_row ), n_col ),
                  v = c( mat ) ) 
out
#>   i j v
#> 1 1 1 1
#> 2 1 2 2
#> 3 2 1 3
#> 4 2 2 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>